# Turn all 'input' items into a list.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to have a user input items into a list, and then have all the items they entered go into a list.

Example:

```
itemList = []
items = input ("Enter all items: ")
```

What I would like to do is, if user inputs "Test Test2 Test3 Test4", each of the items (seperated by the spaces) gets put into the itemList.

Sorry if I did not explain it very well, and I am not sure if this is even possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to visit a tutorial, not ask here. Try https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ . `solution = "One Two Three".split()` does what you want.

Comment: `itemList=input ("Enter all items: ").split(" ")` should be enough

Comment: @mad_: Typically, you'd omit the argument to `split` entirely. That makes it strip leading and trailing whitespace, and split on runs of whitespace, so having two spaces or a tab between your inputs doesn't add an empty string to your result list in the former case, or fail to split at all in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a list consisting of the input string, split on spaces (calling "split()" defaults to splitting a string on spaces).

```
items = input ("Enter all items: ")
itemList = [i for i in items.split()]
print(itemList)
```

Output, using your suggested input:

```
['Test', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4']
```

Comment: `[i for i in items.split()]` is completely pointless. `items.split()` already returns a `list`, wrapping it in a no-op `list` comprehension just makes a new `list` for no reason.